# wildcard and hashbang urls in play routes

Tags: playframework-2.0

In Play 2.4.3 we have some older AngularJS apps which use hashbang routing.  We have a requirement to serve some of these. In other cases it has been straight forward to use routes like this :

```
GET /somepath/*any  @controller.Some.do(any)
```

But when path contains hashbang the globbing fails in the path and it will not match the route.  Has anyone run into this before and know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some examples of the failure you are experiencing?

It seems that the problem may be in the client side (Angular routes). I've used it without problems.

This could be useful to read
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier